# Yeoman copy directory not working

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator

I am trying to copy entire directories as part of a Yeoman generator.  I have multiple functions that call this.fs.copy and it works as expected (for the most part) except **fonts** and **assetsdev**.  I cannot figure out why **assetsdev** task copies the source folder into the fonts directory rather than into the root where I have specified.  Here are my three functions that wholesale copy a directory:

```
    this.props.dotDest = './';
    this.props.srcPath = './assets-dev';
    this.props.destPath = './public/assets';

    dotfiles: function () { // Works as expected. Copies to the root.
        this.fs.copy(
            this.templatePath('dot_files/.*'),
            this.destinationRoot(this.props.dotDest)
        );
    },

    fonts: function () { // Works as expected. Copies to the bootstrap directory.
        var done = this.async();

        this.log( chalk.magenta.bold('Copying /fonts') );
        this.fs.copy(
            this.templatePath('fonts'),
            this.destinationRoot(this.props.destPath + '/fonts/bootstrap')
        )

        done();
    },

    assetsdev: function () { // Does NOT work. Copies to the Bootstrap directory rather than the root.
        var done = this.async();

        this.log( chalk.magenta.bold('Copy assets-dev') );
        this.fs.copy(
            this.templatePath('assets-dev'),
            this.destinationRoot(this.props.srcPath)
        );

        done();
    },
```

I expect the resulting folder structure to be

```
    -assets-dev
    -public
        -assets
            -fonts
                -bootstrap
                    -fontfile
                    -fontfile
                    -fontfile
```

But instead it's generating...

```
    -public
        -assets
            -fonts
                -bootstrap
                    -assets-dev
                    -fontfile
                    -fontfile
                    -fontfile
```

...and I can't figure out why.  I even tried using the async() method in case it was running asynchronously and happened to be in that directory when the **assetsdev** function runs.

Does anyone know why **assetsdev** is copying to the wrong folder? I hope I have explained clearly enough. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently I cant use **destinationRoot()**. Instead I have to use **destinationPath()**.  I am not sure why but using **destinationPath()** copies correctly now.

Comment: `destinationRoot()` assign the root of the project being generated. It doesn't create a path like you expected.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense.  So when I was running it in the previous task it was essentially setting the root folder to that path.  Thanks for the clarification!